# EL in oncomplete attribute of a p:commandLink works only after refreshing the page

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Problem with jsf lifecycle.
The click event of a commandlink is behaving absolutely unexpectedly. I need a dialog to be displayed correctly if the value of the flag is true but this does not happen. It only works if I refresh the page and try again.

This project uses jsf 1.2 and primefaces 6.1.

```
This is the xpto.xhtml page:
<p:commandLink id="btnAdicionaAlunos" styleClass="btn btn-blue"
            actionListener="#{ofertaAlunoController.criarNovaInstanciaOfertaAluno}"
            onstart="showStatus();"
            update=":AgrupamentoOfertaForm:tabView:incluirAlunoOfertaDialog"
            oncomplete="if (#{ofertaAlunoController.isCursoTemMatrizCurricularFlag()}) { PF('incluirAlunoOfertaDialog').show();  hideStatus(); }"
            rendered="#{ofertaAlunoController.permitirIncluirAluno and not ofertaAlunoController.executarFluxoValidacao and ofertaAlunoController.isCursoTemMatrizCurricularFlag}">
            <h:graphicImage value="/resources/imagens/ico-usuario-add.png" />
                    #{bundle['oferta.label.btn.add.aluno']}
                </p:commandLink>
        <p:commandLink id="btnAdicionaAlunosValidacao"
            styleClass="btn btn-blue" onstart="showStatus();"
            update=":AgrupamentoOfertaForm:tabView:#{ofertaAlunoController.dialogValidacao}"
            oncomplete="if (#{ofertaAlunoController.isCursoTemMatrizCurricularFlag()}) { PF('incluirAlunoOfertaDialog').show();  hideStatus(); } "
            rendered="#{ofertaAlunoController.permitirIncluirAluno and ofertaAlunoController.executarFluxoValidacao and ofertaAlunoController.isCursoTemMatrizCurricularFlag}">
            <h:graphicImage value="/resources/imagens/ico-usuario-add.png" />
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="incluirAlunoOfertaDialog"
                target="#{ofertaAlunoController.dialogPosValidacao}" />
                    #{bundle['oferta.label.btn.add.aluno']}
                </p:commandLink>
```

These are the controller methods called on the page:

```
    public void criarNovaInstanciaOfertaAluno() throws Exception {
        limparForm();
        this.cursoTemMatrizCurricular();
        polosAdicionados = this.agrupamentoOfertaController.getPolosAdicionados();
    }

    public void cursoTemMatrizCurricular() {
        Long idCurso = agrupamentoOfertaController.getInstance().getCurso().getIdCurso();
        Curso c = null;

        try {
            c = cursoService.findById(idCurso);
            if (c.getCursosMatrizCurriculares().isEmpty()) {
                this.setCursoTemMatrizCurricularFlag(false);
            } else {
                this.setCursoTemMatrizCurricularFlag(true);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.setCursoTemMatrizCurricularFlag(false);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       

        if (!this.isCursoTemMatrizCurricularFlag()) {
            facesMessager.error(
                    "O curso não possui matriz curricular cadastrada. Cadastre a matriz curricular e aguarde a homologação dela pelo técnico da DED responsável pela homologação para poder incluir os alunos");
        }

    }
```

The first time I click on the commandlink, even though the flag has a value of true, the dialog is not displayed at all.

But if I refresh the page, click the button again and the flag value is true, the dialog is displayed.

Can anyone help me understand what is happening?

I imagined that as soon as the actionListener (criarNovaInstanciaOfertaAluno) was called, naturally, the controller's cursoTemMatrizCurricular would execute and update the flag value.

This even happens but for some reason the dialog is only displayed after the page is manually updated again.

Comment: JSF1.2 is almost 15 years old and so I don't think you will get many people that can help with this here.

Comment: PrimeFaces 6.1 doesnt work JSF 1.2 anyway, just a missinfo propably.